# How to log fmt.Printf in custom file

Tags: go

I have this function which I use to log:

```
func formattedLog(prefix, m string, color int) {
    fmt.Printf("\033[%dm%s", color, DateTimeFormat)
    fmt.Printf("▶ %s: %s\033[%dm\n", prefix, m, int(Black))
}
```

I want to save my log output in some file:

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("../../../go-logs.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error opening logs file", err)
}
defer f.Close()
//set output of logs to f
log.SetOutput(f)
log.Println("This is a test log entry") // <====This logs in file
```

but when I call my function, which uses fmt.Printf it doesn't log in the file `go-logs.txt`:

```
formattedErr("ERR", msg, err.Error(), int(Red))
```

is there anyway to setoutput also for fmt.Printf

Comment: Why do you need to use `fmt.Printf`? You can use `fmt.Fprintf` to write to a file, `log.Printf` to write through the global logger, `log.SetPrefix` to put a prefix on the global logger, and `log.New` to make a non-global logger (this last is what I personally would recommend for any non-trivial project). While you _can_ overwrite global vars in other packages, I personally think that should be a last-resort solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) documents that it writes to the standard output:

> Printf formats according to a format specifier and **writes to standard output**.

So there is no `fmt.SetOutput()` to redirect that to your file.

But note that the standard output is a [variable in the `os`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables) package:

> Stdin, Stdout, and Stderr are open Files pointing to the standard input, standard output, and standard error file descriptors.
>
> Note that the Go runtime writes to standard error for panics and crashes; closing Stderr may cause those messages to go elsewhere, perhaps to a file opened later.
>
> ```
> var (
>         Stdin  = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdin), "/dev/stdin")
>         Stdout = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdout), "/dev/stdout")
>         Stderr = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stderr), "/dev/stderr")
> )
> ```

And you are allowed to set your own [`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) to `os.Stdout`. Although it's not a good idea to use the same `os.File` for a logger and to also set it to `os.Stdout`, access to its `File.Write()` method would not be synchronized between the `fmt` package and the logger.

Best would be to use a [`log.Logger`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger) everywhere (whose output you properly set, so log messages would properly be serialized).